# \comment (verbatim-package) inside \parbox throws errors - What is the problem?

Tags: boxes, verbatim, comments, parbox, compilation-error

I have defined my own environment - lets call it 'myenv' - which shows and hides its content based on some global settings. I'm using the `\comment` and `\endcomment` commands from the `verbatim` package, which work really well for me.

However, i've encountered a strange behaviour when enclosing my environment with a box like this (i reduced myenv to this minimal example):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}

%define my environment
\newenvironment{myenv}{%
    Start:
    \comment
}{%
    \endcomment
    :End
}

\begin{document}
    %\parbox{5cm}{                 % <- this is where it gets strange
         \begin{myenv}
             Content
         \end{myenv}    
    %}                             % <- this is where it gets strange
\end{document}
```

When i enable the `parbox`-lines, i get a list of errors which i don't really understand:

```
Argument of \verbatim@ has an extra }. }
Paragraph ended before \verbatim@ was complete. }
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. }
You can't use `\end' in internal vertical mode. \end{document}
Missing } inserted. \end{document}
Emergency stop.
```

Something seems to break with the `begin` and `end`-points...

---

This also happens with other boxes:

For the `\mbox` the error-list is a bit different:

```
Argument of \verbatim@ has an extra }. }
Paragraph ended before \verbatim@ was complete. }
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. }
Emergency stop.
```

The `\fbox` has another error-signature yet again:

```
Argument of \verbatim@ has an extra }. }
Paragraph ended before \verbatim@ was complete. }
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. }
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. }
Emergency stop.
```

---

The TeX-Primitives `\hbox`and `\vbox` work fine, as does the `minipage`-environment.

So my question is: What is going wrong here and how to resolve this?

Comment: you can not have verbatim (or similar) commands in the argument of another command.

Comment: You can use other forms of "commenting", for example, placing the content inside a (discarded) box.  However, the problem with such an approach is that any counters and lengths (or globally-set variables) that are modified in the comment will carry through to the rest of the document.  `verbatim` approaches avoid that, but as David points out, have their own limitations.

Comment: Thanks! So `minipage` works because it is an environment and `\parbox` doesn't because it gets the content as a regular argument. What about `\hbox` and `\vbox` however?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verbatim like objects are not allowed in arguments to other commands. Since `comment` is implemented the same as `verbatim`, it shares the limitation.

Thus you can't have `comment` in `\parbox`, `\mbox`, `\fbox` and so on.

To the contrary, it can be in `minipage`, because this environment doesn't collect its contents as an argument.

The same for the primitives `\hbox` and `\vbox`. The fact that the syntax is similar to commands with argument is not relevant; indeed,

```
\hbox\bgroup ... \egroup
\vbox\bgroup ... \egroup
```

are allowed (which aren't for ordinary macros); the `{` (explicit or implicit) starts the business of collecting tokens to make up a (horizontal or vertical) list and the final `}` (explicit or implicit) builds the box from the list formed so far.

Basically, `\parbox{<dimen>}{<tokens>}` is

```
\vbox{\hsize=<dimen><tokens>}
```

but the `<tokens>` are absorbed as an argument. Instead,

```
\begin{minipage}{<dimen>}
```

does `\vbox\bgroup\hsize=<dimen>`, while

```
\end{minipage}
```

provides the trailing `\egroup`.